# Assign variables to query mysql on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

Hi I have some problem on nodejs to get data on mysql

My question is 'How can I add var n into "%drawing eye%" to get data on database?'

```
  function showResult(req, res){
                var n = req.query.query
                mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE query_text LIKE "%drawing eye%" ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, rows){
                res.render('result.html',{result:n , related: rows.map(row => row.query_text)})
                })
        }
```

Comment: Try to use mysql query builder it will help you a lot !

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-querybuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do something like this `LIKE "%' + n + '%" ORDER BY`

```
function showResult(req, res) {
    var n = req.query.query
    mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE query_text LIKE "%' + n + '%" ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, rows) {
        res.render('result.html', {
            result: n,
            related: rows.map(row => row.query_text)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: `n` needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` module supports [queries with placeholders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values), where those placeholders get replaced by variables you pass (properly-escaped, to prevent SQL injections):

```
function showResult(req, res) {
  var n = req.query.query;
  mysql_conn.query(`
    SELECT   query_text
    FROM     catalogsearch_query
    WHERE    query_text LIKE ?
    ORDER BY popularity DESC
    LIMIT    0, 10`,
    '%' + n + '%',
    function(error, rows) {
      if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
      res.render('result.html',{result:n , related: rows.map(row => row.query_text)})
    }
  )
}
```

The `?` after `LIKE` is the placeholder, which will get replaced by an escaped version of `'%' + n + '%'`.